# Sort Dictionary Keys using ArrayList

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to sort a dictionary object using an `ArrayList`. The code works, meaning it returns a unique list of values from `Range("A1:A20")`. It just doesn't sort the values. Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Dim rng As ListObject
    Set rng = ws.ListObjects(1)

    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Application.Transpose(rng.DataBodyRange.Value)

    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = GetUnique(arr)

    Dim tempD As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set tempD = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set tempD = SortDictionary(d)

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In d.Keys
        Debug.Print key, d.Item(key)
    Next key
End Sub

Private Function GetUnique(ByRef arr() As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim v As Variant
    Set GetUnique = New Scripting.Dictionary
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each v In arr
        GetUnique.Add v, v
    Next v
End Function

Private Function SortDictionary(dicObject As Scripting.Dictionary, Optional xlSortOrder As xlSortOrder = xlAscending) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim v As Variant
    With obj
        For Each v In dicObject
            .Add v
        Next v
        .Sort
    End With

    Dim tempDic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set tempDic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim k As Variant
    For Each k In obj
        tempDic.Add k, dicObject(k)
    Next k

    Set SortDictionary = tempDic
End Function
```

Comment: You are printing the keys of the unsorted dictionary `d` and not of the sorted dictionary `tempD`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yep, I see it now. Thanks, Ron!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because while you've assigned the sorted dictionary to `tempD`, you're referring to the original unsorted dictionary.  Try...

```
For Each key In tempD.Keys
    Debug.Print key, tempD.Item(key)
Next key
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure how I could have missed that. Thank you!